# define the best possible move (AI - game)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I do not see too how I could set this:
I must code a small IA for asymmetric board game for 2 players. Each turn each player has a number of action points to use to move their pieces on the board (10x10).
For now I know how to generate the list of possible moves for each pawn based on the number of given action point but I block to the next step, selecting the best move. How could I code the fact that for example 5 action points it is best to move one pawn 3 cells and another 2 cells that move one pawn 5 cells. Do I have to use a particular algorithm or apply a programming concept ...? Well, I'm lost.

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Assuming that you are moving only horizontal and vertical then there are 2 simple algorithms you could use DFS(Depth-first search or BFS(Breadth-first search). Check also here https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960215.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign score (evaluation) to each move based on the rules of the game. When you choose appropriate scoring method you can evaluate which out of 5 possible actions is the best one.

As an example let's assume simple game where you must take all opponents pawns by placing your pawn on top of theirs (checkers with simplified/relaxed rules). When you move pawn to the next free cell without exposing your pawn to the danger you can assign score +1 and when you take opponent's pawn +3. If opponent takes your pawn in next move you subtract your score -3. You can define other scoring rules. When you apply scoring to all possible moves you can then select best move either using **MinMax algorithm** for 2 players game or some **greedy search algorithm** which just maximizes the score selecting action which yields highest score on next move without predicting opponent's move.